# Refining HTML Element types in flow

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Is it possible to refine a `Node` or `Element` into a specific HTML element type? For example:

```
function htmlToEntity: (node: HTMLAnchorElement | Node) {
    if (node.tagName === "A") {
      return createEntity(
        "LINK",
        "MUTABLE",
        { url: node.href }, // Throws error
      );
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

The error it throws is:

> Cannot get `node.href` because property `href` is missing in `Node`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `instanceof` to refine it.

```
function htmlToEntity(node: HTMLAnchorElement | Node) {
  if (node instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) {
    return createEntity(
      'LINK',
      'MUTABLE',
      { url: node.href } // Does not throw error
    )
  }
  return undefined
}
```